# Schema hasn't been registered for model :mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a model like this

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema
const fileSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  ownerId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId },
  fileTypeId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId },
  name: { type: String },
  data: { type: Schema.Types.Mixed },
  fileSize: { type: Number },
  isHashInBlockchain: { type: Boolean },
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  updatedAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
})
fileSchema.virtual('file', {
  ref: 'filetype',
  localField: 'fileTypeId',
  foreignField: '_id'
})
fileSchema.set('toObject', { virtuals: true })
fileSchema.set('toJSON', { virtuals: true })
module.exports = mongoose.model('useruploadedfiles', fileSchema)
```

I am referring `filetype` collection to this model

But when I run the following query

```
await File.find(query).populate({ path: 'file' }).select('_id name createdAt updatedAt').sort({ createdAt: -1 }).skip(limit * (pageNumber - 1)).limit(limit)
```

I am getting the following error

```
Schema hasn't been registered for model "filetype"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to import your model in your root app file.

## model.js

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    trim: true,
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: "Please supply a name",
    trim: true
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

app.js

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE);
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise; // Tell Mongoose to use ES6 promises
mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
  console.error(`        → ${err.message}`);
});

// READY?! Let's go!
require('./models/User')
```

## router.js

```
const User = mongoose.model("User");

const getUsers = async (req, res) => res.json(await User.find({}));
app.get('/users', getUsers);
```